# Split Look up table for 128bits setbits calculation

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

How do you use splitting of look-up table for getting the set bits from a string.

I want to implement a split look up table to find the number of 1s in a array.

Thank You,

Comment: What is a setbit-string? Something like "0000:0011" for the byte with value 3? Can you elaborate on the table?

Comment: I know I am late in replying to the comment. But Set bits are bits that are set to 1 for a binary number.